# Twitter API advanced search tweets from user

Tags: javascript, php, api, twitter

Does the Twitter API have a search tool to find specific strings from Twitter historical User timelines without having to load all 3200 tweets and search for it with the needle haystack method?

I read from the documentation that the search twitter API only goes back 7 days which isn't enough.

Twitter's advanced search on its website is much more extensive:

By searching 'clinton from:realdonaldtrump' in twitter, it shows the tweets for several years that have the string 'clinton' in it from the user realdonaldtrump.

https://twitter.com/search?q=clinton%20from%3Arealdonaldtrump&src=typd&lang=en

Does the Twitter API not have a similar function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the basic API doesn't let you go back that far either in a user timeline or in search. The full archive is available as one of Twitter's Gnip APIs.

Comment: thanks, i didn't know about Gnip, i will take a look